# How To create and Send a JSON object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, in-app-purchase

I have a in app purchase store in my app.
Now I need to take the `SKPaymentTransaction` and store the receipt data in to a `JSON` object.
After that I have to send it to apple to validate and get the response from:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

I know how to get the receipt, but I need help from that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everyone uses the fine JSON framework here:
[JSON Framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework)

You can encode and decode JSON with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: Keep in mind iOS 5 provides [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In terms of third-party libraries, [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is more than an order of magnitude faster than json-framework.